# White layer on almost half of the screen

Tags: display

I downloaded League of Legends just to try and when I launched a game, white layer appeared. Here's a screen:

[image]

It's probably dead, nothing can be done now, right?

By the way, it's a laptop and I was "turning up" the light with F5 when it happened.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to check all of your cables connecting your video card and monitor.  Disconnect them and reconnect them, making sure they are all properly seated.

If the problem still exists, you need to determing if its your video card or monitor.  Do you have another monitor to connect to your graphics card?  If so, hook it up and see if the problem persists.  If it does, then you know its the graphics card (Which I feel it is).  If not, then its the monitor.

Either way, if the problem device is under warranty, then get it serviced.  Otherwise, you will need to replace it.

Comment: It's laptop....

Comment: well, you didnt say that and its impossible to see from the picture.  Still it doesnt change the troubleshooting method.  Hook an external monitor to the laptop and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And what if problem persists? And what if it doesn't?

Comment: if it persists the onboard graphics chip has gone bad, most likely.  If not, its the LCD screen.  Laptop LCD screens are replaceable and can be bought from a variety of sources, like the laptop manufacturer, or even eBay.  If its the onboard chip, you are most likely out of luck.  Is the laptop under warranty still?

Comment: No... By the way, it happened when I was "turning up" the light with F5.

Comment: Can it mean something?

Comment: most likely not.